# prevent service restarting in android

Tags: android, service, android-service

i try to use service in my android application but i have a problem. when i press turn on/off button after screen lock the service run with interrupt, it`s look like service is restarting. this is my code :

```
public class MyService extends Service {
private static String TAG = "Service";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
  super.onCreate();
  Log.i(TAG, "onCreate");

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
  return null;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
  Log.i(TAG, "Destroyed");
  super.onDestroy();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
  Log.i(TAG, "OnStartcommmand");
  return START_STICKY;
 }

 }
```

Why My service restart many time ? how can i prevent from service restarting ? is it possible ?
thanks

Comment: return START_NOT_STICKY in onStartCommand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Service` is killed by System to save resources for higher priority apps (for example: when phone runs out of memory). After being killed, your `Service` can be recreated depending on the value returned on `onStartCommand`. If you return `START_STICKY` on `onStartCommand`, System will recreate you service after killing it. Otherwise, `START_NOT_STICKY` tells the OS to not bother recreating the service again.

You can consider to use `startForeground` method to keep your `Service` alive. Here is the documentation:

> A started service can use the startForeground(int, Notification) API
>   to put the service in a foreground state, where the system considers
>   it to be something the user is actively aware of and thus not a
>   candidate for killing when low on memory. (It is still theoretically
>   possible for the service to be killed under extreme memory pressure
>   from the current foreground application, but in practice this should
>   not be a concern.)